# Accessing a SQL view with a stored procedure on another server instance

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have access to a SQL view on say a server called vuk030 and i wish to write and run a stored procedure on a server called vuk386. My question is how to write the sql to access the data in the view on vuk030 as it has a username and password.

the vuk030 server is sql server 2005 and the vuk386 is 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to set up a linked server from vuk030 to vuk386 and enabling RPC over the linked server to make it possible to run stored procedures.

Setup linked server:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998(v=bts.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998%28v=bts.10%29.aspx)

RPC:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186839(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186839%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: I've done this quite a lot. Just make sure to handle errors with a try catch because if the other server is down/network I'd down... you will get errors.